# Update Rails session with Backbone.js history navigate?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, backbone.js

I have a Market stored in a user session in Rails, set via `session[:current_market]` in my `application_controller.rb`.

I have my front-end interface served with Backbone.js, and I have a little market selector widget that calls

```
BackboneApp.data.currentMarket = market.toJSON()
Backbone.history.navigate market.homeUrl(), trigger: true
```

... when a user selects a market. This works except that if a user hard-navigates to another page, the market reverts to whatever it was set on the initial page load (whatever was originally loaded in `session[:current_market]` in Rails.

How can I update the user's market in session when a Backbone.js navigation event occurs?

I tried manually doing this by triggering a silent GET:

```
$.get '/api/v1/reset_current_market', { market_id: market.toJSON().id }
```

... but that doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that when the user switches market then some ajax request will be fired to hit your rails api and fetch the data for that market. What you could do is make the controller action for that route update the current users session to whatever market got requested.

Comment: Yeah, played around with this along these lines and got it working. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

how about wrap this market info to new Model and handling change with that? This is just a pseudo code examlpe.

```
var marketModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
        urlRoot:"/you/url/market",
        defaults:{
            marker: ""
        },
        initialize:function () {
        }
    });
BackboneApp.data.currentMarket = new marketModel(market.toJSON())
```

Set selected market to this new model, and call save().
At rails change session info at your /your/url/marget POST method. If this object have id property then impelent also PUT method.